# How to check services are running or not in Solaris

Tags: samba, services, solaris

Particularly, I want to check Samba services and see if it is running or not in Solaris machine.

For Linux, we can check with below command.

```
service smb status
smbd (pid  8058) is running...
```

Answer (score 2):

Unlike on Linux, there's a unified service system on Solaris. It is called SMF. To check if a service is running use the `svcs` command. `svcs -a` will give you status of all services configured on the system, including disabled services.

Here's an example where I already know the service name, in this case `/network/http:apache22`, which is my Apache Web server. Using the `-l` and `-p` switches I can get a lot of information about the service, including what dependencies it has (pre-conditions) and what processes IDs it is currently executing under.

```
$ svcs -lp /network/http:apache22
fmri         svc:/network/http:apache22
name         Apache 2.2 HTTP server
enabled      true
state        online
next_state   none
state_time   Tue Dec 27 09:53:38 2016
logfile      /var/svc/log/network-http:apache22.log
restarter    svc:/system/svc/restarter:default
contract_id  76060
manifest     /lib/svc/manifest/network/http-apache22.xml
manifest     /lib/svc/manifest/network/http-squid.xml
dependency   require_all/error svc:/milestone/network:default (online)
dependency   require_all/none svc:/system/filesystem/local:default (online)
dependency   optional_all/error svc:/system/filesystem/autofs:default (online)
process      2474 /usr/apache2/2.2/bin/httpd -k start
process      13181 /usr/apache2/2.2/bin/httpd -k start
process      13183 /usr/apache2/2.2/bin/httpd -k start
process      13184 /usr/apache2/2.2/bin/httpd -k start
process      13185 /usr/apache2/2.2/bin/httpd -k start
process      13186 /usr/apache2/2.2/bin/httpd -k start
process      13187 /usr/apache2/2.2/bin/httpd -k start
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `ps -ef` to find the services running or not on a Solaris machine:

```
$ps -ef |grep smbd
root  3214  3886   0 20:49:40 ?           0:03 /usr/local/samba64/sbin/smbd -D
root 15273  3886   0   Nov 07 ?           0:04 /usr/local/samba64/sbin/smbd -D
root 23061  3886   0 11:12:30 ?           0:01 /usr/local/samba64/sbin/smbd -D
```